# How to get the arguments during a custom defined command?

Tags: vim

I have this custom command that I want to define. But I can't manage to get the arguments separately:

```
:command -nargs=2 :%s/<args1>/<args2>/gc // <args1> <args2> dont work
```

Anyone has some solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<args1>` and `<args2>` doesn't exist. You invented this yourself. The easiest way to do this is to use a function wrapper and `<f-args>`:

```
fun! s:sub(search, replace)
    execute ':%s/' . a:search . '/' . a:replace . '/gc'
endfun
command! -nargs=+ Replace call s:sub(<f-args>)
```

`<f-args>` splits the the command arguments at whitespace and adds proper quoting and commas, in order to pass it to a function.

Using a function wrapper also has the added benefit of resetting the `@/` register after its finished running. If you don't want this, then explicitly assign it with `let @/ = a:search`.

Other than this, almost everything about your `:command` call is wrong:

- `-nargs=2` isn't supported − see [`:help :command-nargs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3acommand%2dnargs)
- You forgot to fill in the command name.
- `//` isn't used to denote comments in  VimScript; `"` is used for that.

See [`:help :command`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3acommand) for a full description of the syntax.